# Popen getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, subprocess, popen

Hello i m trying to use Popen to open a .py and pass arg, if necessary, to it.

exemple:

```
python mytool.py --first-arg player1 player2 player3 --second-arg 10 --tenth-arg 150
```

I m using a tkinter button to start this funcion, it **works on Windows** using python 3.7
but **not on linux**, getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "mytool.py", line 131, in start
    obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(first_arg, second_arg, third_arg, fourth_arg, fifth_arg, sixth_arg, seventh_arg, eighth_arg, ninth_arg, tenth_arg, eleventh_arg, twelfth_arg))])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1453, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

The code i m using is this one:

```
def start(self):
    first_arg = ("--first-arg ", self.first_arg_entry.get())
    second_arg =   ("--second-arg ", self.second_arg_entry.get())
    third_arg = ("--third_arg-arg ", self.third_arg_entry.get())
    fourth_arg = ("--fourth-arg ", self.fourth_arg_entry.get())
    fifth_arg = ("--fifth-arg ", self.fifth_arg_entry.get())
    sixth_arg = ("--sixth-arg ", self.sixth_arg_entry.get())
    seventh_arg = ("--seventh-arg ", self.seventh_arg_entry.get())
    eighth_arg = ("--eighth-arg ", self.eighth_arg_entry.get())
    ninth_arg = ("--ninth-arg ", self.ninth_arg_entry.get())
    tenth_arg = ("--tenth-arg ", self.tenth_arg_entry.get())
    eleventh_arg = ("--eleventh-arg ", self.eleventh_arg_entry.get())
    twelfth_arg = ("--twelfth-arg ", self.twelfth_arg_entry.get())
    thirteenth_arg = (self.vold.get())
    print ("Tool started in terminal")
    self.bt_stop.config(state=NORMAL)
    self.disable_buttons()
    global obj
    if self.vold.get() == "":   
        obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'mytool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(first_arg, second_arg, third_arg, fourth_arg, fifth_arg, sixth_arg, seventh_arg, eighth_arg, ninth_arg, tenth_arg, eleventh_arg, twelfth_arg))])
    else:
        obj = subprocess.Popen([self.Tipvar.get(), 'myool.py', *filter(lambda x: bool(x[1]) ,(first_arg, second_arg, third_arg, fourth_arg, fifth_arg, sixth_arg, seventh_arg, eighth_arg, ninth_arg, tenth_arg, eleventh_arg, twelfth_arg, thirteenth_arg))])
```

What can I be doing wrong and what can be done to work on **Linux/Windows**?

Hope you help me.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your question also lacks  some research (just search for the error message) and a [mcve].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for replying, i have already research about it but not found a similar case, i think that my problem is related with the necessity of filter on that subprocess. but not sure how to solve it. do you have any information that can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, extracting a [mcve] is a way to diagnose the problem, which is why I mentioned it. Also, it allows others to run your code and also look for a solution. This is also why it's actually required for a question here.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending tuple(args in round brankets) in the subprocess call, which I think is causing the issue.

Pls. check the subprocess documentation for more details, how to pass the args and also use the `type()` operator if you are not sure about the datatypes

Comment: given the example above, would you know what to do to resolve this issue? Thanks for your time.

Comment: As you can see i need filter the information if entry is empty.

Do you have any idea what should be done to solve this issue?